# Vectorize replacement of sub-sub list elements in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, nested-lists

I have a somewhat complicated data structure (a nested list) `y`, defined as:

```r
x <- list(
  list(1, "a", 2, "b", 0.1),
  list(3, "c", 4, "d", 0.2),
  list(5, "e", 6, "f", 0.3)
)
y <- rep(list(x), 10)
```

I also have a data frame `df`, defined as:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = c( 0.33, 1.67, -0.62, -0.56,  0.17, 0.73,  0.59,  0.56, -0.22, 1.49),
  x2 = c(-0.82, 1.22,  0.65,  0.54, -2.26, 1.21, -0.44, -0.92, -0.56, 0.50),
  x3 = c(-0.16, 0.49, -0.82, -0.71,  0.13, 1.22,  1.23, -0.01, -1.11, 0.97)
)
```

where the column names are not important.

I want to replace `y[[i]][[j]][[5]]` with `df[[i, j]]` for all `i` and `j`.  My Python/Julia brain works best in loops, so I have accomplished this by looping over `y`, and then over the elements of `y` (each a copy of `x`), like so:

```r
for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    y[[i]][[j]][[5]] <- df[[i, j]]
  }
}
```

This works, but for my much larger data set, it is really slow. So I am trying to vectorize the nested `for` loop.  I have been experimenting with `Map()`:

```r
y_new <- y
for (j in 1:3) {
  y_new <- Map(function(sublist, value) { sublist[[5]] <- value; sublist },
               y_new, df[, j])
}
```

but the above does not work, since `identical(y, y_new)` returns `FALSE`.  I think I am missing a level of subsetting.

I am not married to `Map()` at all.  I am just looking for the fastest possible alternative to the nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@akrun's suggestion to unlist and relist is elegant and highly idiomatic ("R-like").

But I would want to do that without coercions, especially from numeric to character and back, which can be slow and result in loss of precision.  Something like this would be faster and safer:

```r
unlist0 <- function(x) unlist(x, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
split0 <- function(x, f) unname(split(x, f))

n <- length(y) # 10
n1 <- length(y[[1L]]) # 3
n11 <- length(y[[1L]][[1L]]) # 5

uy <- unlist0(unlist0(y))
uy[seq.int(n11, n * n1 * n11, n11)] <- as.list(t(df))
suy <- split0(split0(uy, gl(n * n1, n11)), gl(n, n1))
```

Here's a benchmark:

```r
unlist0 <- function(x) unlist(x, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
split0 <- function(x, f) unname(split(x, f))

n <- length(y) # 10
n1 <- length(y[[1L]]) # 3
n11 <- length(y[[1L]][[1L]]) # 5

library(purrr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
colebrookson =
    {
        ans <- y
        for (i in seq_len(n))
            for (j in seq_len(n1))
                ans[[i]][[j]][[n11]] <- df[[i, j]]
        ans
    },
TarJae =
    {
        map2(y, asplit(df, 1L), ~ map2(.x, .y, ~ { .x[[n11]] <- .y; .x }))
    },
akrun.1 = 
    {
        Map(function(u, v) Map(function(uu, vv) { uu[5L] <- vv; uu }, u, v), y, asplit(df, 1L))
    },
akrun.2 = 
    {
        uy <- unlist(y)
        uy[seq.int(n11, n * n1 * n11, n11)] <- c(t(df))
        type.convert(relist(uy, y), as.is = TRUE)
    },
`Mikael Jagan` =
    {
        uy <- unlist0(unlist0(y))
        uy[seq.int(n11, n * n1 * n11, n11)] <- as.list(t(df))
        split0(split0(uy, gl(n * n1, n11)), gl(n, n1))
    },
times = 1000L
)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq       max neval
 colebrookson 1116.635 1171.6365 1318.72441 1195.2115 1238.077 16936.567  1000
       TarJae  297.783  314.8390  365.66412  331.7105  352.026  1554.679  1000
      akrun.1   76.096   82.4305   96.82716   87.0840   91.676  2076.117  1000
      akrun.2 1206.343 1231.1685 1345.24661 1244.2270 1261.222  5023.197  1000
 Mikael Jagan   35.465   40.9590   51.61260   45.7765   50.594  1271.984  1000
```

Some remarks:

- Don't read into benchmarks on small examples.
- I suspect that only the fourth and fifth answers will scale well, since only those vectorize the replacement.
- Only the fourth answer is not identical to the first, in the sense of `identical`. It differs due to loss of precision.

Comment: Ok wow this is great, thanks so much!! I would not have thought of this approach at all. Just out of my own curiosity, was there something specific in the problem that led you to thinking of doing the `unlist0`/`split0` as a function? I wouldn't have guessed that so curious what your thought process was

Comment: The problem with `unlist` is that by default (`recursive = TRUE`) it concatenates all of the leaves of the tree, resulting in coercions if those leaves have different types. Calling `unlist0` twice ensures that we remove only two layers of nesting, leaving behind a list preserving the types of its elements. The problem with `relist` is that it assumes that we _did_ perform the recursive unlisting. So we use `split0` twice (with different groupings) to invert the `unlist0` calls one by one _without introducing names_, which `split` by itself does.

Comment: Defining functions is just a way to avoid repeating yourself when you want to do something more than once. DRY, etc. (But you probably knew that.)

Answer (score 4):

With `Map`, we may do

```
y_new <- Map(\(u, v) Map(\(uu, vv) {uu[5] <- vv; uu}, u, v), y, asplit(df, 1))
```

-testing with OP's code

```
> for(i in seq_len(length(y))) {
+   for(j in 1:3) {
+     y[[i]][[j]][[5]] <- df[[i, j]]
+   }
+ }
> 
> all.equal(y_new, y)
[1] TRUE
```

---

As a vectorized approach, an option is to `unlist` and assign

```
v1 <- unlist(y)
v1[seq(5, length(v1), by = 5)] <- c(t(df))
y_new <- type.convert(relist(v1, skeleton = y), as.is = TRUE)
```

-checking

```
> for(i in seq_len(length(y))) {
+   for(j in 1:3) {
+     y[[i]][[j]][[5]] <- df[[i, j]]
+   }
+ }
> 
> all.equal(y, y_new)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `map2` twice:

First we use `asplit(df, 1)` to convert the data frame `df` into a list of vectors. The first `map2()` iterates then over `y` and the list of row vectors, and the second `map2()` replaces the 5th element of each nested list in `y` with the corresponding value from df.

We use curly braces `{}` and a semicolon `;` to combine multiple expressions into a single expression.

```
library(purrr)

map2(y, asplit(df, 1), ~ map2(.x, .y, ~ { .x[[5]] <- .y; .x }))
```